# how to remove a column including delimeter using AWK command "."?

Tags: awk

i have an input file like this:

```
01.gold 1 1986 USA American Eagle
02.gold 1 1908 Austria-Hungary Franz Josef 100 Korona
03.silver 10 1981 USA ingot
04.gold 1 1984 Switzerland ingot
```

i want to remove the fields before and including ".". the desired output is :

```
gold 1 1986 USA American Eagle
gold 1 1908 Austria-Hungary Franz Josef 100 Korona
silver 10 1981 USA ingot
gold 1 1984 Switzerland ingot
```

please explain a little.
thanks in advance. :)

Answer (score 2):

`sed` would be easier in my opinion.

```
$ sed 's/^.*\.//' file
gold 1 1986 USA American Eagle
gold 1 1908 Austria-Hungary Franz Josef 100 Korona
silver 10 1981 USA ingot
gold 1 1984 Switzerland ingot
```

`^.*\.` means look at the start and match any character until you see a literal `.`. Replace it with nothing.

Couple of ways with `awk`:

Logic is similar to `sed` given above. Using `sub` function.

```
$ awk '{sub(/.*\./,"")}1' file
gold 1 1986 USA American Eagle
gold 1 1908 Austria-Hungary Franz Josef 100 Korona
silver 10 1981 USA ingot
gold 1 1984 Switzerland ingot
```

This one is tricky and could break if you have `.` more than one time in your string.

```
$ awk -F'.' '{print $2}' file
gold 1 1986 USA American Eagle
gold 1 1908 Austria-Hungary Franz Josef 100 Korona
silver 10 1981 USA ingot
gold 1 1984 Switzerland ingot
```

From the comments (Thanks [Ed](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1745001/ed-morton)):

```
$ cut -d'.' -f2- file
gold 1 1986 USA American Eagle
gold 1 1908 Austria-Hungary Franz Josef 100 Korona
silver 10 1981 USA ingot
gold 1 1984 Switzerland ingot
```

Comment: Another option is `cut`: `cut -d. -f1 --complement file` i.e. with delimiter ".", print everything except first column.

Comment: Just add `cut -d'.' -f2- file` to complete the set.

Comment: Why is the dot in your second `awk` example escaped?

Comment: @AdrianFrühwirth Thanks fixed. Also removed it from the first one since it wasn't needed.

Answer (score 0):

Her is another `awk`

```
awk 'BEGIN {FS=OFS="."} {$1=""; sub(/\./, "")}'1  file
gold 1 1986 USA American Eagle
gold 1 1908 Austria-Hungary Franz Josef 100 Korona
silver 10 1981 USA ingot
gold 1 1984 Switzerland ingot
```